# Intersect Two DataFrames In Pandas Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have two data frames that look similar to the ones represeted below.

```
df1
            id          date        x  w
    0       71896517    2020-07-25  1  5
    1       71896517    2020-09-14  2  3
    2       72837666    2020-09-21  1  9
    3       72848188    2020-11-03  1  1


df2
            id          date         x  y  z
    0       71896517    2020-07-25   1  1  6
    1       71896589    2020-09-14   2  2  8
    2       72837949    2020-09-21   1  1  3
    3       72848188    2020-11-03   1  1  2
```

I want to achieve only one data frame by intersecting the tow data frames above and achieve something similar to:

```
        id          date        x  w   y   z
0       71896517    2020-07-25  1  5   1   6
1       71896517    2020-09-14  2  3   NaN NaN
2       71896589    2020-09-14  2  NaN 2   8
3       72837666    2020-09-21  1  9   NaN NaN
4       72837949    2020-09-21  1  NaN 1   3
5       72848188    2020-11-03  1  1   1   2
```

Pretty much I want for every date the information for each id to be on the same row. I left the NaN because I think that is how it is going to be presented, but then I will fill them with zero.
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try an outer merge:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').sort_values('date').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df3)
```

`df3`:

```
         id        date  x    w    y    z
0  71896517  2020-07-25  1  5.0  1.0  6.0
1  71896517  2020-09-14  2  3.0  NaN  NaN
2  71896589  2020-09-14  2  NaN  2.0  8.0
3  72837666  2020-09-21  1  9.0  NaN  NaN
4  72837949  2020-09-21  1  NaN  1.0  3.0
5  72848188  2020-11-03  1  1.0  1.0  2.0
```